# How are stand-alone Toasts implemented in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm implementing a custom toast component in a React app. I basically have a container where I display all active toasts. I can trigger a toast from anywhere in my app using context API. My question is, if I want to trigger a toast from outside a React component e.g. a global error handling function, how should my implementation change to be able to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what kinds of errors outside your React app you expect to be handling?

Comment: My current implementation relies on context API and hooks. So for example, when using React Query, I can pass an error handler function which among other things, might display the error to the user in a toast. The logic for this error handler is not in a React Component or hook, hence I cannot access values inside React Context.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are migrating your app to React and are in a need of using some legacy code, there is no need to make any calls from outside of React. Even for global error handling, because you can use *error boundaries* and additionally subscribe to the *window* object's global error events from within any React component.

Having said that, I'd recommend to use the [events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/events) library or any similar as your solution.

Just emit events in your global function:

```
eventBus.emit('addToast', { message: 'Pass it to a toast' });
```

and subscribe to them inside a `useEffect` in any of your components that can trigger toasts:

```
useEffect(() => {
  eventBus.on('addToast', addToast);
  return () => eventBus.removeListener('addToast', addToast);
}, []);
```

To access the same instance of the *event bus* you can create a module and import it your other modules:

```
// EventBus.js - A simple global event bus
import EventEmitter from 'events';
export const eventBus = new EventEmitter();
```